# How to reduce false positive in opencv_traincascade

Tags: java, opencv

EDIT MY QUESTION
I have noticed that if I train the pattern with 24 - 28 stages, the result is better, but I need more more images, at least 1000 negatives and 1000 positives, because the algorithm can't get more samples if you have fewer images.

---

I have a problem, I had investigated and I haven't could to find a good option for that:

I'm doing my own patter with opencv 3.2.0, y use 331 positive images and 412 negative images, I need to find power line poles in images (this is just one element, I need to find more, but I have to do a patter for each one).

My code for opencv_samples is: opencv_createsamples -info info_positivas.info -num 331  -w 50 -h 50 -vec prueba_vec.vec

My code for opencv_traincascade: opencv_traincascade -data resultados -vec prueba_vec.vec  -bg negative\bg.txt -numStages 10 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -numPos 250 -numNeg 250 -w 50  -h 50 -mode ALL -precalcValBufSize 1024 -precalcIdxBufSize 1024 -baseFormatSave
(I tried to use -numPos 331 -numNeg 412 but I have an error, it left to appear when I change those numbers, and I didn't understand why).

When the process finish, I obtain an xml with the pattern, but when I tray to use (program with java), I see many error, many false positives, and sometimes never match with the correct imagen
[red: all errors I see, blue: I have to recognize that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7WVi.png)

I put an url with my files, negative (inside is a txt with a list of negative images), rawdata(positives), vector of positive images, a list of them (info_positivas.info), my class in java (I use just one) and the imagen to run the class.

[Link to my images](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5QJXuQClhniOWttQ1lxdUp0THc?usp=sharing)

I don't know if are the images, the parameters, or something else.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: may be change library ? http://blog.dlib.net/2016/10/easily-create-high-quality-object.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, my inconvenient now is I have to do my project with java, but this article helps me to know more about object detectors, I read about library deeplearning4j, it's something similar but for java. Thanks!!